# Install .NET Framework 4 (or 4.6) in Windows Server 2016

Tags: installation, .net-framework, windows-server-2016

I was trying to test our products to make sure that they are compatible with Windows Server 2016. And during some testing, I mistakenly thought that I can simply "downgrade" .NET framework from 4.6 to 4. So I removed .NET 4.6 from Roles and from IIS.

Now, I can't install it back using installer (because its part of OS so it is asking me to enable it from role & features). And I can't start server manager (to install role & features) because it needs .Net 4 at minimum.

[image: 1.Server Manager Error 2. .NET4 Setup Error]

So I am stuck. Do I have any other option than reinstalling OS ? I have sent so much time testing this system, I would rather not do it if possible.

UPDATE: 
I already tried [.NET installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48137) for older Windows OS but it didn't help.

Comment: Try this offline installer (.NET 4.6): https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48137

Comment: Tried it already. Unfortunately it ends with message that this is not for your OS. Apparently it's not for 2016.

Comment: Maybe can this helps: http://www.technig.com/how-to-install-windows-features-offline-using-dism/

Comment: @dude , downloading iso from MSDN and then going to try. Though not have very high hopes because DISM document doesn't mention support for Server 2016. I will post my finding here.

Comment: @dude, It worked !! I "enabled" 4.6 and everything is back on track. I can't believe that. This has literally saved me 2 days of re-setup time. I really appreciate your help. If you put your suggestion in answers and I will accept it as answer (and add comment about command that helped) so future visitors can be benefited.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to to [install .NET Offline using DISM](http://www.technig.com/how-to-install-windows-features-offline-using-dism/) like in this example for .NET 3.5:

Type the following command:
`“Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Netfx3 /source:D:\Sources\sxs”` and then press enter. It take a while and when the process has finished, close the PowerShell Windows then go to check the exact windows features must be installed successfully.

Thank you @JackLock for this comment:

So based on your suggestion, I enabled feature called "NetFx4". 
Since it was already installed, I didn't need to provide source of it. So my command looked like

`Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx4 /All`

Comment: So based on your suggestion, I enabled feature called "NetFx4". Since it was already installed, I didn't need to provide source of it. So my command looked like `Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx4 /All`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you duDE and JackLock. Both of your answers helped me to fix this problem.

**My problem:**
On Windows Server 2016, the .NET Framework 4.6 had been inadvertently uninstalled from my system while trying to fix some issues with IIS. It was removed using the Server Manager > Remove Roles and Features.

As a result, the Power Shell, Server Manager, and Event Viewer were no longer working. So I downloaded and installed the latest offline version of the .NET Framework 4.7 from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55167) using the installer. However, it did not fix the problem when installed by clicking on the installer.

**Solution**
To fix the problem, I had to install it from the command line using the "/all" switch. I unzipped the installer to a folder and here is the command that I used to install it. In the last argument in quotes is the path to the installer, which will need to be modified based on where you have the installer unzipped:

```
Dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:Netfx4 /source:"E:\t\NDP47-KB3186497-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU (Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7)"
```

Comment: It’s not possible for .NET Framework 4.6 to be uninstalled from Windows Server 2016 (it’s built-in).  The command you issued installed .NET Framework 4.7 which replaced .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6 can be uninstalled from Windows Server 2016, but it does cause a number of built-in applications to also not work (such as ServerManager).