# Windows server 2016 , unable to install .net framework

Tags: .net-framework, windows-server-2016

I accidentally removed .net framework 4.5 feature from server manager in windows server 2016 machine.
Now I'm not able to open any windows component (server manager , IIS , Powershell ...) where I'm getting this error :

> To run this application,you first must install one of the following
>   versions of the NET Framework: v4.0.30319 Contact your application
>   publisher for instructions about obtaining the appropriate version of
>   the .NET Framework.

I tried to install .NET Framework 4.7.1 , the installation finishes successfully , but when I reboot my computer , it turns up that the .net framework is not installed.

When I try to install v4 I get :

> Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already a part of this operating system,
>   but it is currently turned off. To enable the .NET Framework 4 , use
>   Turn Windows features on or off in Control Panel.

But unfortunately I'm not able to access server manager to install the feature.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: See this.....https://www.raymond.cc/blog/add-or-remove-windows-features-through-the-command-prompt/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install .NET Framework 4 (or 4.6) in Windows Server 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1183705/install-net-framework-4-or-4-6-in-windows-server-2016)

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following command on CMD as administrator.

> Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx4 /All

I Hope this can help you.